# Need more than 10 lookup filter criterias

Tags: lookup, lookup-filter, dependent-lookup

I have 2 objects lets say **Contract** and **CustomA__c**. Both these Objects have same record types names (**Contract** has types A,B,C.., and **CustomA__c** has types A,B,C..).
I have lookup field on Contract To CustomA__c, and I need to show only the records that are same record types in my lookup.

What I have tried:

**1)** Check **Contract** record type name and then check **CustomA__c** Record type NAME and if they both match that is the solution. Problem here, is that i have **7** record types and i need total of **14** criteria fields for that, Salesfroce only give me 10.

Example:

```
Contract: Contract Record Type equals FOO
CustomA: Record Type: Name equals FOO
```

**2)** I tried to create a formula field on **CustomA__c** to get record type name, problem here is, you can't use formula fields in lookup filters.

Also what is wierd to me, is that i can't reference record type name in lookup filter for standard object. e.g: `Contract: Record Type: Name`, i can only do `Contract: Contract Record Type` which is recordTypeId standard field and i cant match by that value.

Anybody has ideas or faced the problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Search options and functionality can differ a bit depending on whether you're in Classic or LEX. That having been said, the issue you're encountering is because you're not including a field along with the object when specifying the record type in your filter criteria.

Your filter criteria should look like the following:

```
Contract Name: Contract Record Type  equals value  My Record Type Name
```

You may find [Lookup Filter Examples](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=fields_lookup_filters_examples.htm&type=5) in the Salesforce Help a useful resource to look at when writing your filter criteria.

Comment: I solved the issue. I did create a picklist on Contract record and used formula to populate a default value based on record type $RecordType.name. And then i compared this picklist value to my custom object record types. Also i did make the picklist read-only on page layout. Works fine.